# How to add up pandas dfs that contains some nan value while retaining all values (i.e. 0+nan=0)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

As title, how can I add up pandas dfs that contains some nan value while retaining all values in those entries(i.e. 0+nan=0)?

DF1=

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | nan | nan |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | nan |

DF2=

| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Expected output=

| A sum | B sum | C sum | D sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | nan | nan |
| 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Sorry if the question is too basic, thanks for answering.

Comment: `df1.add(df2.to_numpy(), fill_value=0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `add` with `fill_value=0` and to avoid index alignment by covering `to_numpy`:

```
df1.add(df2.to_numpy(), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
    A1   B1   C1   D1
0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
```

With column names:

```
(df1.add(df2.to_numpy(), fill_value=0)
    .rename(columns=lambda c: c[:-1] + ' sum')
)
```

Output:

```
   A sum  B sum  C sum  D sum
0    0.0    0.0    NaN    NaN
1    0.0    2.0    2.0    1.0
```